# Is it possible to disable a congnito user pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to disable the cognito user pool to deny all users access to the application while performing a matainance, and we don't have a switch off mechanism.

Is it possible to do this?

I've tried by disabling the settings in Client Applications, but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to disable a User Pool, however you can create a custom Pre authentication hook with Lambda and basically have it deny all authentication requests.

Then when your maintenance is over, just remove the hook from the pool.

See [Pre Authentication Lambda Trigger documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html)

Example of how you could achieve this with a custom Lambda

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    if (downForMaintenance) {
        var error = new Error("App is down for maintenance. Please check back later.");

        // Return error to Amazon Cognito
        callback(error, event);
    }

    // Return to Amazon Cognito
    callback(null, event);
};
```

Be aware that this method would only prevent people from logging in and getting a new token from the pool while active. Depending your app server implementation, they could still use tokens that they already had prior to maintenance.